# Are Tutte's results still valid for planar graphs with multiple edges?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, hamiltonicity

Tutte proved the famous result: **Every planar 4-connected graph has a hamiltonian cycle**.  But I read in Section 111.6.5 on book *Eulerian Graphs and Related Topics*  that the author Herbert Fleischner places **great importance on the impact of simplicity on this theorem**. Even its proof in the end is based on refuting simplicity. What puzzles me is that multiple edges seem not to affect vertex connectivity and planarity. Why is the condition of simple graphs used here?
[image]

Are there counterexamples to Tutte's results for 4-connected planar graphs with multiple edges?
That is to say, are there 4-connected planar non-hamilton multi-graphs?

Comment: It's my understanding that the results holds for multigraph. The proof uses the fact that a minimal (with respect to subgraph inclusion) counter-example must be simple, and reach a contradiction.